# Would it be possible to use Objective-C code in Cocos-2DX while on Android?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, iphone, cocos2d-x

I realize that none of the native iOS libraries would be available, but would it be possible to write some of the game logic in Objective-C and then link it into the respective operating system at a lower level where needed (via c on Android or objective-c on iOS)?

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: @NSPunk Good question! - We are evaluating options for taking code from iOS to a more general system, but many parts of our code rely on Obj-C style introspection and dynamic method calling. We currently use a system called Apportable which is a cross compiler, but we would prefer to do it manually and link into the cross platform capabilities of a game platform like Cocos2D-X while still using our own game engine.